# How do I split my screen into two full screen tabs on Chrome and on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, display

Can one have two web pages, each full screen - i.e. hide tabs and url bar - but side by side, in a browser like Chrome or the  Windows 10 desktop? What is the  easier way (I'm a newbie) to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Have the separate tabs open on each monitor and press F11 on your keyboard.

You can separate the tabs into different windows to have one on each screen by either click and holding the tab you want to move to your second screen and dragging it away from your primary monitor - or alternatively, right click the Chrome icon in the task bar and click "New Window"

If you need to hide the bookmarks bar too, the shortcut is ctrl+shift+B.

Comment: OP wants this on one monitor not two